# Vue js emit between three components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Card component that emits a string when clicked, then my carousel component will emit the string that was emited by the card back to its parent. The card component emit works fine but the carousel component does not work.

Card emit:

```
<div class="card m-0 p-0" @click="$emit('setMovie', movieKey)">
```

Emit from Carousel:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
     <div class="row ml-1">
         <h1>{{selectedMovie}}</h1>
         <MovieCard v-for="m in movies" :key="m.MovieKey" @setMovie="$emit('setMovie', movieKey)"/>                      
     </div>
</div>
```

Home Component (not detecting emit from Carousel):

```
<Carousel v-bind:movies="movies" @setMovie="test"/>

methods: {
    test(){
      this.testData = "movie changed";
    }
  }
```

The Carousel @setMovie emit is not detected on the Home Component.

Comment: I hope that what you posted above is not your exact code. As you have typos, such as `mothods`

Comment: I would agree with @T. Short here - you wouldn't see the result of the test method in your home component because you have spelled method wrong.

Comment: wow, I feel so stupid. That was exactly the problem, I think I'm gonna delete this post. I there a plugin for vs code where it checks typos?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventBus implementation in Vue. You would emit an event from methods (or anywhere you want) in one component and you would register listeners during the lyfecycle hooks of other components.

Answer (score 0):

`$emit` events should not be camel case. Use kebab case instead.

try:

```
@click="$emit('set-movie', movieKey)
```

and then in carousel:

```
@set-movie="$emit('set-movie', movieKey)
```

and in parent

```
@set-movie="test"
```

Comment: not sure the casing of the event matters - i use camel case throughout without issue

Comment: The case matters only in DOM templates.